# How to upload an existing file from filesystem to aws s3 in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have two service namely view(doesn't store anything) and user(stores the records). View fetches and uploads the data to user service. I am using em-http-request for the interaction between the two apps. Now, to upload user's photo, I need to first store it in a temporary storage and then upload it to s3. It is not advisable to store it directly on to amazon s3 and wait for the response.
What I am trying to do is:
1. Save the image onto temporary storage, say public/uploads..
2. Save the data in user service, with photo_url as "public/uploads/photo1.jpg"
3. Upload the saved photo(retrieve with the url) to s3 and get it's response in **background Asynchronously**
4. Upon receiving the response, Updating the record back to user service with the new photo_url.

I am done with step 1 and 2, and will be done with step 4 as well. The important part is step 3.
1. Workers -> Which ones are better: Starling and working or Sidekiq(it uses redis internally)
2. Services to use:  aws-sdk, carrierwave, paperclip.
I can use amazon-sdk with any of the workers above, but it won't provide me the with the features such as resizing and other cool stuff.
Personally I want to use carrierwave, but not able to get a good idea in this scenario. Also, if this task can be done without using any of these workers, there is no problem.

I have coded this:

```
    user_params = params['user']
    uploaded_io = user_params['photo']
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
    user_params['photo'] = 'public/uploads/' + uploaded_io.original_filename
```

Next, I am seding user_params to user service and updating the database.
Here step 3 will be accomodate.

A whole different approach for uploading the file will also be appreciated.  Thanks